# Can someone help tell me whether this is an application-based or object-based error?

Tags: excel, vba

I've never programmed in VB before and I'm trying to get a bit of code working in an Excel workbook.

Can someone please tell me whether it's an application-based or object-based error? Or if I am doing something completely wrong lmao.

Please excuse me, I've literally taught myself in 5 minutes and tried to make this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim carryover As Integer, name As String, index As Integer, globIndex As Integer

globIndex = 2

For i = 2 To 255
    
    index = i
    carryover = Cells(AI, index).Value
    name = Cells(A, index).Value & Cells(B, index).Value
    If carryover > 0 Then Cells(AK, globIndex).Value = name
    If carryover > 0 Then Cells(AL, globIndex).Value = carryover
    If carryover > 0 Then globIndex = globIndex + 1
    Next i
    
    
    

MsgBox "Please check cell ranges AK and AL in the previous month for names being carried over to next month"
End Sub
```

Comment: Rows first, then Columns, and the column name needs to be in quotes: `carryover = Cells(index, "AI").Value` - Or just `carryover = Range("AI" & index).Value`

Comment: What error are you talking about ? I don't see an error, just code.

Comment: So I'm guessing you haven't got `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.  So your column references that haven't got the quotes as @brax said are being translated to variables with a non-value of `empty`.  It then tries to reference `Cell(empty, 2)` which is column 2, row ??? and throws your error.  Add `Option Explicit` to the top and your message will turn to `Variable not defined`.

Comment: Help on [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement)

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values Greater Than Zero

- This will only happen once, when the workbook is opened.

**`ThisWorkbook` Code Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRow As Long = 255
    Const globStart As Long = 2
    
    Dim globIndex As Long: globIndex = globStart
    Dim index As Long
    Dim carryOver As Long
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Me.Worksheets(wsName)
        .Columns("AK:AL").Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1) _
            .Offset(FirstRow - 1).ClearContents
        For index = FirstRow To LastRow
            carryOver = .Cells(index, "AI").Value
            If carryOver > 0 Then
                .Cells(globIndex, "AK").Value = .Cells(index, "A").Value _
                    & .Cells(index, "B").Value
                .Cells(globIndex, "AL").Value = carryOver
                globIndex = globIndex + 1
            End If
        Next index
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Please check columns `AK` and `AL` in the previous month " _
        & "for names being carried over to next month"

End Sub
```